# Symfony/BowserKit No devuelve HTML puro

Tags: php, symfony, scraping

Estoy intentando realizar un poco de Scraping junto con DOMCrawler component. Mi problema es que el BrowserKit me devuelve siempre un dump antes que el HTML y no se como acceder al mismo

¿Hay alguna forma de modifiacar eso? El codigo de arriba es lo que me devuelve el dump y de alli no se como seguir

Edit1: He conseguido que el HTTPClient me devuelva el string de HTML (eliminando el HttpBrowser) y asi poder ver el documento sin tener que hacer un dump y verlo como objeto. Hay alguna forma de pasar esta respuesta del HTTPClient a la clase deñ HTTBrowser? Necesito pasar formularios que el Client no me reconoce pero el Browser si.

```
<?php 

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\HttpBrowser;
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;

    Function Connect($url) {
    
        $browser = new HttpBrowser(HttpClient::create());
        $browser->request('GET', $url); 
        /* Printing results;
        print_r($browser);
        var_dump($browser);*/
        
        $browser->getContent();
        echo($browser);
    }
    Connect('https://motherfuckingwebsite.com/');
?>
```

```
Function Connect($url) {
        $browser = (HttpClient::create());
        $response = $browser->request('GET', $url); 

        $content = $response->getContent();
        echo $content;
        //$crawler = new Crawler($content);
    }
    Connect('https://www.google.com/');
```